# Facing Null Pointer Exception: Cannot invoke method firstMethod() on null Object : Grails 3.2.10

Tags: grails, groovy

I wrote a simple rest-api Controller in Grails 3.2.10 version. Below are my system configurations. Created application is also rest-api profile.

Grails Version: 3.2.10
Groovy Version: 2.4.10
JVM Version: 1.8.0_131

Sample code written is as follows:
Controller:

```
package mydevpath

import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*

class LoginController {
static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

def index() {
        def loginService
        def val = loginService.firstMethod()

        render 'hello World' + val
     }
   }
```

Service :`
     package mydevpath

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

 @Transactional
 class LoginService {
    static scope = "prototype"

     def firstMethod(){
        return 'From Service'
  }
}
```

On running and hitting the URL , I am facing below error.

```
NullPointerException occurred when processing request
: [POST] /login
Cannot invoke method firstMethod() on null object. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.
invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
        at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrai
lsControllerClass.java:188)
```

Can somebody help me with the Issue?

Regards,
Pramod

Comment: `loginService.firstMethod()` is causing issue. where is `loginService` initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service should be declared outside of the index action:

```
package mydevpath

import grails.rest.*
import grails.converters.*

class LoginController {
static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

def loginService

def index() {
    def val = loginService.firstMethod()

    render 'hello World' + val
}
}
```